# Updating Node.js on Ubuntu - version not changed after update

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to update Node.js on Ubuntu by commands:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest
```

I got response:

```
installed : v16.6.1 (with npm 7.20.3)
```

But when I'm checking the version by `node -v` or `nodejs -v` I'm getting:

```
v10.19.0
```

Is it required to manually change the system paths? Old version is not replaced?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the path for the new `node` is not included in `$PATH`.

you can check that by running `which node`, it will print the path to `node` cli.

you can fix it by including the path which `n` install node to the system PATH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Ubuntu 21.10, and I was able to fix it and get the correct version of nodejs to show in my terminal.

The solution is to Set 16.6.1 (or another version) as default

```
 nvm alias default 16.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ sudo npm cache clean -f
$ sudo npm install -g n
$ sudo n stable
```

Upgrade to the latest version, you can use

```
$ sudo n latest
```

Fix PATH:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy
```

**Note:** Need to restart your terminal